# Deriving axis/angle rotation from two pairs of three points (or, two pairs of two vectors)

Tags: math

Please note that although it sounds similar, this is not the common "how to rotate one vector onto another" question.

I would like to derive an affine transform (either in matrix or a quaternion+vector form) from two sets of 3 points. Those can be regarded as "marker points" on rigid bodies, or as the endpoints of "forward and up" vectors.
Translation and rotation is necessary, scaling is not necessary. Also, a quaternion+vector solution would be a plus, since it would allow me to cram 1/3 more instances into a drawing batch (8 uniforms instead of 12).
The intent is to have a system for determining the pose of (articulated or not) ridid bodies in an intuitive way, without needing to maintain and walk a complicated hierarchy.

The first obvious simplification is to eleminate the translational part by picking one of the points and subtracting the "destination" from the respective "start" point. Now we only need to deal with a rotation.

There is a well-known, computionally inexpensive solution of constructing a quaternion that rotates one vector onto another, namely q(cross(v1,v2) ; sqrt(v1.len_sq * v2.len_sq) + dot(v1,v2)) or q(cross(v1,v2) ; 1 + dot(v1,v2)) for unit-length vectors. Unluckily, this method has no notion of an "up direction", and therefore always roates on the shortest arc (which will misalign objects).
The naive thing to do would be to simply use this method for both vectors and multiply the quaternions together, but it obviously won't work that easily.
What one would need to do is pick one of the two vectors (let's call that one "forward"), and create a quaternion for this one, then rotate the other ("up") vector using this quaternion, then construct a second quaternion for the rotated "up" vector (and the target "up" vector), and finally multiply the second to the first quaternion. This will be correct as far as I can tell, but it is also *horribly* complicated.

Now... as for rotation matrices, I am aware of the "triad method" which I understand as follows:
- Orthonormalize the vector pairs (both start and end)
- This results in two orthonormal bases which are the respective rotational matrices for start and end from a "common reference frame". It does not matter what reference frame exactly this is, all that matters is that it is the same for both.
- S is the transform from the "common frame" to the start frame, and D is the transform to the end frame, respectively.
- Therefore, S<sup>-1</sup> * D * v transforms any point from the start to the end coordinate system (going via the common reference frame).
- S<sup>-1</sup> == S<sup>T</sup> since it is an orthonormal matrix, and S<sup>T</sup> * x = x * S
- Therefore: S<sup>T</sup> * D * v = D * S * v

This should work, but it still seems quite complicated for something that should actually be really, really simple.

Is there an easier, more straightforward solution?

Comment: i believe this is a good candidate for `http://math.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with the rotation part only, your second method will work and I suspect it will work well.  Alternatively, you could use a hybrid of the two methods which might be a bit easier.  Assume the two pairs of two vectors you constructed above, each pair in its own vector space.  Compute the orthormal basis of each pair and call them X<sub>0</sub> and X<sub>1</sub> in one vector space, and their corresponding vectors Y<sub>0</sub> and Y<sub>1</sub> in the other vector space.  You now have to compute two quaternion rotations:

1) q<sub>0</sub> rotates X<sub>0</sub>, and X<sub>1</sub> to X'<sub>0</sub> and X'<sub>1</sub> respectively such that X'<sub>0</sub> = Y<sub>0</sub>.  X'<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>1</sub> should now be coplanar with plane normal X'<sub>0</sub> = Y<sub>0</sub>.

2) q<sub>1</sub> rotates X'<sub>1</sub> to X''<sub>1</sub> = Y<sub>1</sub>.  All you need to do is compute the angle between the vectors since you already know the rotation vector will just be X'<sub>1</sub> x Y<sub>1</sub> = X'<sub>0</sub> = Y<sub>0</sub>

You can calculate q = q<sub>1</sub> * q<sub>0</sub> to perform the rotation in a single step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I must admit that I don't understand your approach, even after sleeping over it and reading again. But that is probably just me :-)
It does not seem to be computionally less intensive, so maybe there is no significantly easier (i.e. computionally less expensive) approach at all?

Comment: The limitation I see in your first approach is that the vectors in each reference space are not orthogonal. This makes computing the second rotation angle more difficult. By orthogonalizing them first and then applying what is essentially the first approach you describe, it trivializes computation of the rotation vector (it's just +/-Y0) and makes computation of the rotation angle easier (just cos^-1 of the inner product). Not sure if it'll perform better than either of the other two methods (they're all constant time) ... that's what profiling is for.

Comment: Another thought: What if one builds two orthonormal bases and uses the first one to "unrotate" the second. Then, simply do a matrix to quaternion conversion on the unrotated second base.

That isn't precisely cheap (2 orthonormalizations, one matrix multiply, a horizontal add, and a couple of square roots), but it's still kind of reasonable... and probably cheaper than the other two methods. And, it outputs a quaternion, so only 4 float 4 values, which is nice. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Your "horribly complicated" quaternion solution would not generally work. You would have to project the second pair of vectors on the plane orthogonal to the axis of the first rotation to make sure that the second rotation is orthogonal to the first one.

I have described the principle in my blog if you are interested: http://robokitchen.tumblr.com/post/67060392720/finding-a-rotation-quaternion-from-two-pairs-of-vectors

Before rotation: u0, v0. After rotation: u2, v2.

```
Quaternion q2 = Quaternion::fromTwoVectors(u0, u2);
Vector v1 = v2.rotate(q2.conjugate());
Vector v0_proj = v0.projectPlane(u0);
Vector v1_proj = v1.projectPlane(u0);
Quaternion q1 = Quaternion::fromTwoVectors(v0_proj, v1_proj);
return (q2 * q1).normalized();
```

I'm not sure this is the solution you want but the code runs surprisingly fast.

Comment: Looks great, and by the looks should be much faster than my implementation with matrices. Unluckily I'll not have an occasion to try and implement and test it before Christmas. Will definitely do, though.

Answer (score 1):

We have to solve this exact same problem. Here's how I do it:

Call the points P and W, so we have P1..P3 and W1..W3

Construct three vectors in each space like so

```
A1 = P2-P1
A2 = P3-P1
A3 = A1 x A2
```

and

```
B1 = W2-W1
B2 = W3-W1
B3 = B1 x B2
```

These two pairs of three vectors each constitute a non-orthogonal basis, and you want to find how to represent your cartesian axes (x y and z) in one space so that you can find them in another. To do this construct a matrix so that its columns are the three vectors found above. Then invert this matrix, if this inversion fails, then the non-orthogonal basis does not span the space and the problem cannot be solved.

Then pull the three columns out of the inverted matrix. These columns are the cartesian axes in terms of your non-orthogonal basis (V1, V2 and V3). From this we can reconstruct an orthogonal basis that will serve as a transformation matrix from the first space to the second.

If we call this matrix R, and denote R[row, column] as our notation, then the rows (or columns, depending on how you use the matrix) of the final transformation matrix will be:

```
B1 * R[0,0] + B2* R[1,0] + B3 * R[2,0]
B1 * R[0,1] + B2* R[1,1] + B3 * R[2,1]
B1 * R[0,2] + B2* R[1,2] + B3 * R[2,2]
```

Now, because one of the columns of the original matrix before the inversion was the cross of the other two columns, it's probably possible to optimise the inversion of the matrix. I haven't bothered to do this - especially because in our case the three points P1..P3 don't change, and so the inverted matrix can be cached.

This method has the advantage that if you have a half-decent matrix/vector library it's very simple to implement. And it doesn't use angles, which is always a good thing.

Comment: I must admit that I still can't 100% follow, even after reading it 3 times, giving it a month break, and reading it again (the last code section is just one column of the matrix?). What you describe seems to be similar to the "triad method" as outlined in the question, except you do not orthonormalize the base (which means you can represent shear and scale, but the inverse is not as simple as transposing).

Comment: It's possible that my explanation isn't as clear as it might be. What I'm effectively saying is that the answer is in the question. That is, you want to transform from one basis to another, and you have both bases. The only complication is that your two bases are not orthogonal, and orthonormalising them is one approach that will work. I personally think it's conceptually simpler to calculate the representation of the cartesian axes in your first basis so that you can transform them into your other basis, but they are probably equivalent methods.